# spark read from hiveserver2 (JDBC ) Remote Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive, apache-spark-2.0

I have requirement of Reading from Hive Source Table from different Cluster - I am trying to research how this can be achieved? I am planning to use HiveServer2 ( JDBC ) connection as an option. Can someone please refer me some sample code or some Reference URL.

I tried using "hive-jdbc.jar", and below piece of code, it printsSchema but when used with Show() method - it fails.

```
 val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://34.223.237.55:10000")
  .option("dbtable", "students1")
  .option("user", "hduser")
  .option("password", "hadoop")
  .option("fetchsize", "20")
  .load()
```

Note :  Hive is Kerberized

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

**Reference problem :**

[image]